# Probability distribution function of components of a random vector with a fixed norm

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, vectors, random-variables, expected-value

I have a process which generates random vectors in n-dimensional space with the condition that all generated vectors have the same norm, $K$, for example. Every possible vector with this norm has an equal chance of being generated. How can I find the probability distribution function for the value of a single vector component?

That is, we have a random vector $\textbf{X}=\{X_1, ...,X_n\}$, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_i)^2=K$. How can we find the probability distribution function $f$ of $X_i$.

I have plotted a histogram of the component values from randomly sampled vectors in 5-dimensions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbLUy.png):

Comment: You mean the vector ${\bf X}$ likes on the surface of a hypersphere in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Exactly like that. It is trivial to generate samples from the distribution, however I can't find any way to describe the distribution mathematically.